# How do I sort JSON from least to greatest in Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, sorting

Lets say I have a JSON file like below:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "fork"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "knife"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "spoon"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am unsure how I sort the data inside data[] so it would be something like below (the id and name sorted by least to greatest). I tried a sorted() function but I am completely unsure how this would work.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "knife"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "fork"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "spoon"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Show what you tried. Also your JSON is invalid. Post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You can use `key` parameter:

```py
dct = { "data": [ { "id": 2, "name": "fork" }, { "id": 1, "name": "knife" }, { "id": 3, "name": "spoon" } ] }

output = {'data': sorted(dct['data'], key=lambda d: d['id'])}

print(output) # {'data': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'knife'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'fork'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'spoon'}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort by id

`sorted(data, key=lambda x: x['id'])`

Comment: I got this error running it with my JSON: ```TypeError: string indices must be integers```. Any idea why?

Comment: @StatureOfficial No, but update your question with your code and valid JSON so your problem can be reproduced